# Group Players into Teams

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to group a list of players into teams for an  multi-round event with a minimum of 3 and a max of 4 players per team. They are already randomly seeded and ranked according to seed. But need to pair them according to rank for future rounds.This needs to be scalable depending on how many players attend.

For example:
12 players get split into 3 4-player teams.
13 players get split into 1 4-player team and 3 3-player teams.

I am familiar with how to do this with loops in most programming languages but would appreciate some guidance in doing this with google sheets/excel.

Comment: I want to prioritize grouping as many into 4s as possible while the remainder are in 3s. I did a really complicated solution but it’s really shaky and requires some manual intervention as the math breaks down due to my own spreadsheet inexperience. 

Here is a brief example of what I’m looking for. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-kQaVM2FsB_YkfACCqXwEA8uaJQ7w6RU8z-ZOUkPJmI/edit

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a math problem than a formula problem :)

For `x` players, `x>6`, to be grouped in groups of 3 and 4 only, and prioritizing groupings of 4, you will have `int(x/3)-mod(x,3)` groups of 3 and `mod(x,3)` groups of 4.

When you know this, there are a bunch of options to work with, like if the rankings are ordered, you can just use that with even more maths, to calculate the group (something like `D2` being `=IF($C2>4*MOD($B$18,3),INT(($C2-4*MOD($B$18,3)-1)/3)+MOD($B$18,3)+1,INT(($C2-1)/4)+1)`). Basically if doing it like this, with maths, you're substituting loops for checks with `MOD`, and it can get complicated, luckily this is a rather simple case.

Another possible solution, that I won't write out due to it possibly being even more complicated, is with `ARRAYFORMULA`, `SEQUENCE` and `REPT`, where you do sequences of four of the same number while still dealing with groups of 4, and sequences of 3 afterwards. It still uses a similar check as the first one, the advantage of this however is that it automatically fills up the table without needing to drag it down. This functionality could also be implemented in the first solution too (put it all in an `arrayformula` and change all mentions of `$C2` to `$C2:INDIRECT("C"&$B$18+1)`).